# Storing custom Type in SQLite .NET field

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, system.data.sqlite

We are using SQLite.Net in a C# application and I want to define a property on one of the classes that gets stored on the db as having a custom type.

The type is essentially an Enum and a string, can be serialised to a string representation and I have overridden ToString

What is the correct way of getting this type in and out of a Field?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using SQLite.Net or SQLite.Net.Async? The latter has IBlobSerializer interface that supports converting custom types to byte arrays and back. I normally serialize the custom types as JSON to a byte array.

Comment: Async, I went with defining the property as a string and converting my type to a string when it is passed in the end. Thanks